# Difference between document.getElementById and document.getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

In particular why does document.getElementsById work here

```
<div id="move">add padding</div>

<button type="button" onclick="movefun()">pad</button>

<script>
function movefun() {
    document.getElementById("move").style.paddingLeft = "50px";
}
</script>
```

but document.getElementsByClassName does not work

```
<div class="move">add padding</div>

<button type="button" onclick="movefun()">Set left padding</button>

<script>
    function movefun() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("move").style.paddingLeft = "50px";
    }
</script>
```

I have left out the common things like the html and body tag to cut down on code length.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection, not a single element.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because `getElementsByClassName` ***returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names.***

Use this instead if you want to do it by class

DEMO 1 -> http://jsfiddle.net/1r0u5d3o/2/

`document.getElementsByClassName("move")[0].style.paddingLeft = "50px";`

Or if you want to do it to all the elements of the class, use a loop

DEMO 2 -> http://jsfiddle.net/1r0u5d3o/1/

```
function movefun() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("move");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        elements[i].style.paddingLeft = "50px";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`getElementById` returns a single DOM element whose ID matches your query. `getElementsByClassName` returns an `HtmlCollection` - an array-like structure containing the DOM elements that matched your query. You have to iterate through each element in the array to apply your style.

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementById("move") returns html element

document.getElementsByClassName("move") returns html collection
```

`style` is a property of html element hence, works fine with `getElementById`

For reference -

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Answer (score 0):

We want to get the unique element and allocate it in a variable this can be done by making use of getElementById.
But when we want to get all the products elements and allocate them in a variable then basically we are using getElementByClassName.