# btn1.addEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, dom, javascript-objects

```
<div class="content-text">
                    <h1 class="colorchange">STATUE OF UNITY</h1>
                    <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                         Necessitatibus sint nisi animi ipsum commodi illum fuga eos 
                         ad. Amet consectetur fugit adipisci praesentium rem eaque eos
                          laudantium, vitae sunt earum.
                    </P>
      </div>
```

```
<script>
        const clr=document.getElementsByClassName("colorchange");
        const btn1=document.getElementsByClassName("btn");

        btn1.addEventListener("click",myfunction)
        function myfunction(){
            clr.style.display="none";
        };
    </script>
```

I am not understand this error can you please tell what is the problem in my code??????????????.

Comment: I do not see any element in your html having 'btn' class. Please add that element then try.

Comment: If you have only 1 element you want to hide then I suggest just using the id of that element, `getElementsByClassName` returns an array like object and you will have to access them by their index

Answer (score 1):

[getElementsByClassName vs getElementsById](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31974582/difference-between-document-getelementbyid-and-document-getelementsbyclassname) your code will return a list of all the elements which contains `colorchange` in class.. therefore you need to get the first element

```js
const clr = document.getElementsByClassName("colorchange");
const btn1 = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");

function myfunction() {
  clr[0].style.display = "none";
};

btn1[0].addEventListener("click", myfunction)
```

```html
<div class="content-text">
  <h1 class="colorchange">STATUE OF UNITY</h1>
  <P>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus sint nisi animi ipsum commodi illum fuga eos ad. Amet consectetur fugit adipisci praesentium rem eaque eos laudantium, vitae sunt earum.
  </P>
  <input type="button" class="btn" value="hide">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns the HTMLCollection. It's array-like object.

You need to have a button with class "btn" in your code, and write smth like this:

```
const btn1 = document.getElementsByClassName("btn")[0];
```

or by using `querySelector`:

```
const btn1 = document.querySelector(".btn");
```

and then call:

```
btn1.addEventListener(...your code...)
```

Best regards!